# Отсутствует MSVCP110.dll

Tags: библиотеки, exe, visual-studio, c++, dll

Как создать .exe файл так, чтобы он содержал в себе все нужные для его работы библиотеки?

Проведя немало времени на форумах, делаю следующим образом:

- Создаю новый пустой проект в Visual Studio;
- Выбираю: Проект -> Свойства -> C/C++ -> Создание кода -> Библиотека времени выполнения -> Многопоточный DLL (/MD).

Причем настройки выставляю для Release версии.
Но при попытке запустить программу на компьютере, который не обладает данной библиотекой, выскакивает ошибка: Такая-то библиотека не была найдена. Попробуйте переустановить приложение.

Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: @Антон Вахрушев, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте /MT
Сайт макрософта:

> None, static link. Multithreaded,
> static link /MT
> _MT

Answer (score 1):

вообще, когда необходима dll, то для универсальности ее обычно тащат вместе с программой, включая в дистрибутив. Отправляют либо в windows\system32, либо, что более здраво с моей точки зрения, размещают в папке с программой, указывая откуда брать дополнительные библиотеки

Comment: Не-не-не, только не со своими dll'ками в системный каталог! Прямой путь в DLL hell, клиенты будут оччччень рады.

Comment: Так что здравый вариант = единственный. (Ну или упомянутая в альтернативном ответе статическая линковка.)